# Django: Applying mutilple access control decorators to a view

Tags: django, authentication

I'm attempting to expose a single API call using three different authentication mechanisms: django's login_required , HTTP basic auth, and OAuth. I have decorators for all three but can't quite figure out how to have them all get along smoothly.

The required logic is to allow access to the view if any of the decorators / authentication mechanisms are valid for the user's request - basically an OR. However, if I simply include all three decorators then they all want to be satisfied before letting the request through - an AND.

What's a good way to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can. Suppose the user isn't logged in: if using `login_required` the server would redirect to a login form, whereas using basic auth, the server would return a 401 error page with a `WWW-Authenticate` response header. Which of these do you want to happen? I don't see how it could be both.

Comment: For my API I allow HTTP Basic Auth AND test for sessioned users but I don't use login required.  I don't redirect to the login url on failure, I return the 401 error instead. This allows a logged in user to test the API but doesn't cause a conflict for non-browser access if basic auth or oauth fails.